# Another PartCover Empty Report Question

Tags: nunit, partcover, nunit-console

I've tried the steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702071/partcover-console-produces-empty-output-xml), but I still can't get partcover to generate any output other than:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PartCoverReport ver="2.2.0.36423" />
```

Here is what I've done:

1. Installed 2.2 instead of 2.3
2. Ran corflags /Force /32bit+ PartCover.exe
3. Ran corflags /Force /32bit+ PartCover.browser.exe

Here is my command line:

```
partcover --target nunit-console-x86.exe --target-args unittests.dll  --include +[*]* --output c:\temp\out.txt
```

When I run that command, here is the output I get:

```
Start target
Wait results
NUnit version 2.5.0.9117 (RC)
Copyright (C) 2002-2008 Charlie Poole.\r\nCopyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newki
rk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.\r\nCopyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig
.\r\nAll Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.0.6002 Service Pack 2
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.4200 ( Net 2.0.50727.4200 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-2.0.50727.4200
.Gendarme v2.4.0.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2009 Novell, Inc. and contributors

Initialization: 1.1 seconds
unittests.dll: 2.4 seconds

One assembly processed in 3.5 seconds.
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
.................................
Tests run: 1076, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0 Time: 19.071907 seconds

  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0

Walk results
```

Does anyone have any suggestions that might help?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is what I did to fix the problem, in addition to the steps above:

Add a settings file:  settings.xml

```
<PartCoverSettings>
  <Target>nunit-console-x86.exe</Target>
  <TargetArgs>unittests.dll</TargetArgs>
  <Rule>+[*]*</Rule>
</PartCoverSettings>
```

Run with this command line:

```
partcover --settings settings.xml --output out.xml
```

And that produces an XML file.

I also didn't need to downgrade to 2.2.  2.3 seems to work fine for me now...